# Search query a custom post type by title and another custom post type linked to it by an ACF relationship field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to configure my custom search bar and query in Wordpress to search for custom post types named : "Engagements". 
Each "engagement" is linked to a "company" using the ACF relationship field.

I need the search bar to search inside the titles of these engagements and at the same time to search by the linked custom post type "Companies".

I've managed to search for engagements using this query. But how can I add an 'OR' to the query so that the search can show the engagements linked to certain Companies ?

```
$query = $_POST['query'];

$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' =>  'engagements',
    's' => $query
);

query_posts( $params );
global $wp_query;

if( have_posts() ) :

    ob_start(); 
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();

             get_template_part('partials/engagement', 'thumb'); 

    endwhile;

    $posts_html = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 
else:
    $posts_html = '<div>No results</div>';
endif;
```

Comment: See this page https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I know how to query posts that are linked using the relationship Field. But the query uses the ID's of the relationship linked posts. The Problem is I need to Search by title of the linked post. I won't know the id's

Comment: Probably run a query to search "Companies" title to get a list of IDs and pass that along to query_posts? No elegant but quicker to implement.